# How to hold MySQL query result in an int variable if possible

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to know whether a table exist or not before creating another one is there any way of holding result in a variable after execution of command, i am using this code but it keeps giving only true even if table doesn't exists.

```
public static boolean checkBefore(){
    boolean r = false;
    try{
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'sms' AND table_name = 'auth';";
        con = connectsms();
        st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        r = rs.next();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorMsg,"Exeption Fount: "+e,"Opps! Exception Found in checkBefore()",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    }
    System.out.println(r);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not show the logic for creating another table. What exactly do you want to achieve? Check if the statement `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);` returns anything?

Comment: i have not include code to create table first i want to create logic to check and return false if table does not exist. and that statement returns some string but its constant everytime i execute code

Comment: Did you check this select statement `COUNT(*)FROM`? add a space before `FROM`.

Comment: Did you try [`ResultSet::getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int))?

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/304006/databases/execute-scalar-query

Answer (score 1):

Every JDBC guide will show you that after executing a query, you need to call `next()` to advance to the next/first row, then call getter methods to retrieve the column values of that row.

Queries with aggregating functions (`COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc) without a `GROUP BY` clause will always return exactly one row, so for those kinds of queries, you don't need to check the return value from `next()`. For pretty much all other queries, you do.

When calling JDBC methods that return resources, you should use try-with-resources to make sure those resource are cleaned up correctly.

Query string does not need to end with a `;` semi-colon.

All that means that your code should be:

```
public static boolean checkBefore() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)" +
                  " FROM information_schema.tables" +
                 " WHERE table_schema = 'sms'" +
                   " AND table_name = 'auth'";
    try ( Connection con = connectsms();
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    ) {
        rs.next(); // exactly one row returned, so next() always returns true here
        int count = rs.getInt(1); // get value from first column
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
        return (count != 0);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorMsg, "Exeption Fount: " + e,
                                      "Opps! Exception Found in checkBefore()",
                                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `r = rs.next();` to `rs.next();` and then add `r = rs.getInt(1) > 0;` and it will work.

Comment: You can't call `rs.getInt(...)` before calling `rs.next()`

Comment: Should i use this code to full fill my need

```
 public static boolean checkBefore(){
        boolean r = false;
        try{
            query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userdata";
            con = connectsms();
            st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
           
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            return false;
        }
        
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that worked for me:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'databse_name';
```

and the code that i am using and is working correct:

```
public static boolean checkBefore(){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        query = "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'sms'";
        con = connectsms();
        st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        result = rs.next();
        System.out.println();
    }catch(SQLException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorMsg,"Exeption Fount: "+e,"Opps! Exception Found in checkBefor()",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    }
    try{
        con.close();
        }
    catch(SQLException e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorMsg,"Exeption Fount: "+e,"unable to close connection",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); }

    System.out.println(result);
   return result;
}
```